# Dagger 2 injecting parameters of constructor

Tags: android, dagger-2

I saw the following example on the [Dagger 2 website](http://google.github.io/dagger/):

```
class Thermosiphon implements Pump {
  private final Heater heater;

  @Inject
  Thermosiphon(Heater heater) {
    this.heater = heater;
  }

  ...
}
```

and the documentation:

> When a new instance is requested, Dagger will obtain the required
>   parameters values and invoke this constructor.

When I write a Module to provide a `Thermosiphon` like

```
@Module
public class ThermosiphonModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Thermosiphon provideThermosiphon() {
        return new Thermosiphon(???);
    }

}
```

the `Thermosiphon` constructor still requires a `Heater` as an argument, rendering the whole 'automatic injection of constructor dependencies' useless.

I tried

```
return new Thermosiphon(null);
```

and

```
return new Thermosiphon();
```

(empty constructor) and hoped for Dagger2 to pick up that I wanted the missing `Heater` to be injected, yet the Heater of the provided `Thermosiphon` is always null;

I verified though my `HeaterComponent` / `HeaterModule` are working fine and are able to provide a `Heater`.

Do I completey misunderstand the whole feature of 'Dagger satisfies constructor dependencies for you' or am I missing something?

Comment: Adding this documentation which explains that you do not need to create a provider when an object has `@Inject` annotation to its constructor, which makes sense since Dagger now already know how to create an instance of the object.


https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html#defining-dependencies-object-consumers

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you're using modules, then if you have two provider modules bound to the same component, then you'll be able to allow them to see the heater as a constructor parameter.

```
@Module
public class HeaterModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Heater heater() {
        return new Heater(); // if not using @Inject constructor
    }
}

@Module
public class ThermosiphonModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Thermosiphon thermosiphon(Heater heater) {
        return new Thermosiphon(heater); // if not using @Inject constructor
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules={ThermosiphonModule.class, HeaterModule.class})
public interface SingletonComponent {
    Thermosiphon thermosiphon();
    Heater heater();

    void inject(Something something);
}

public class CustomApplication extends Application {
    private SingletonComponent singletonComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        this.singletonComponent = DaggerSingletonComponent.builder().build(); //.create();
    }

    public SingletonComponent getSingletonComponent() {
        return singletonComponent;
    }
}
```

---

But with constructor injection, you will also be able to provide objects of that given scope, or unscoped objects, as long as they have a `@Inject` constructor.

For example,

```
@Singleton
@Component // no modules
public interface SingletonComponent {
    Thermosiphon thermosiphon();
    Heater heater();

    void inject(Something something);
}
```

And

```
@Singleton
public class Heater {
    @Inject
    public Heater() {
    }
}
```

And

```
@Singleton
public class Thermosiphon {
    private Heater heater;

    @Inject
    public Thermosiphon(Heater heater) {
        this.heater = heater;
    }
}
```

Or

```
@Singleton
public class Thermosiphon {
    @Inject
    Heater heater;

    @Inject
    public Thermosiphon() {
    }
}
```

Comment: @EpicPandaForce excuse me, could you help me on this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43308649/6596724 Thanks

Comment: My question is: are you able to mix those two dependency Injections Rules?
`class Usecase @Inject constructor(val restApi: RestService)`
and than 
`class ViewModel{
lateinit var usecase : Usecase
init{
        Application.getRestComponent().inject(this)
    }
}`

Comment: Answer for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287645/dagger-2-injecting-constructors

Comment: good help for understanding the alternative way of using constructor injection vs. using module.

Answer (score 33):

For one, since you've annotated the constructor of `Thermosiphon` with `@Inject`, you don't need an `@Provides` method. Dagger uses this constructor to create an instance when needed. Just annotate the `Thermosiphon` class itself with `@Singleton` to preserve the singleton behavior.

If you do want to use an `@Provides` method, and to answer your question fully, you can specify the `Heater` as a parameter to the method:

```
@Module
public class ThermosiphonModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Thermosiphon provideThermosiphon(Heater heater) {
        return new Thermosiphon(heater);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it mean that you can use Thermosiphon for field injection as well without needing to define a provider? I was confuse when I tried to use a class that annotates its constructor with `@Inject` for field injection and it works without any provider.